# Laravel Eloquent: order results by field in related table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

How do I order the results of a query by a field in a related table?

I have two tables,

table users:
id, first_name, last_name, etc

table videos:
id, user_id, title, etc

Model: Video

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

For example I am querying all videos where title = "video 1" and using skip & take for pagination/pager.

I now want to order this list of videos by the users first name.

```
$query = \App\Models\Video::where('title','=','Video 1')->skip(0)->take(10);
```

What is the best/efficient way of doing this? I can't order the array/collection after the query as then the pagination won't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
$query = \App\Models\Video::where('title','=','Video 1')
->join("users","users.id","=","user_id")
->orderBy("users.first_name")->skip(0)->take(10);
```

Comment: Good question, I was just lead to believe that I should be using the models for relationships rather than joins. These videos can be searched for on multiple fields, even by username so I have been using sub-queries etc. Is the method you suggested superior?